# Asymptotic estimation of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have an integral of the form
$$
I = \int\limits^{1}_{0} \exp\left(\dfrac{vt}{(v+1)^2 + v^2} - vt\right) dv
$$
and I want to prove that $I\leq c t^{-1}$ for the sufficiently large $t$, where $c$ is a constant independent of $t$.
Can anyone give me some hints or references to prove this expansion?

Comment: The integrand is less than $\exp(-2tv^2)$.

Comment: The bound $\exp(-2tv^2)$ gives $O(t^{-1/2})$ for the integral, not $O(t^{-1})$.  And indeed plotting the value of the integral strongly suggests  an asymptotic value about $0.63 t^{-1/2}$. So I believe the claim is false.

Comment: A lower bound is $\exp(-\frac45 t v^2)$.  This completes the proof that the value is $\Theta(t^{-1/2})$.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay: Thank you very much, Professor McKay. I think you are right because my estimate is the same as yours.

Comment: @BrendanMcKay Upper and lower bounds look interchanged (without affecting the resut).

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune  Quite right, thanks. Upper and lower are interchanged.  Also, for large $t$ the lower bound is sharper and that suggest the asymptotic value is $\sqrt{\pi/8t}$ which matches experiment.

Comment: Your title is misspelled, but the typo cannot easily be fixed since there is another question with the (correctly spelled) title.  Please pick a new, correctly spelled title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This question should be on math.stackexchage.com.)

Substitute $v=t^{-1/2}u$, then it becomes
$$ t^{-1/2} \int_0^{t^{1/2}} e^{-2u^2}\bigl(1 + O(u^3/t^{1/2})\bigr)\,du
= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8t}} + O(t^{-1}).$$

Comment: Answering questions that belong on MSE here on MO doesn't help to convince people to put them where they belong, though.  If one must answer, then I think that it is better to do it as a comment.  Either way, it is probably a good idea for you to vote to closre or migrate.

Comment: @LSpice You are quite right and I voted to migrate.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that is exists a $k$ such that

$$\dfrac{vt}{(v+1)^2 + v^2} - vt=-\frac{2 v^2 (v+1)}{2 v^2+2 v+1}t\sim -k\,v^2\,t$$

The integral would be
$$I\sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2} \frac{\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{kt}\right)}{\sqrt{kt}}$$ Expanded for large values of $t$

$$I \sim\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{k t}} -\frac{e^{-k t}}{\sqrt{\pi } k t} \right)$$

Such a $k$ exists and its value is $\sim \frac 53$